# Move QML function to another qml file

Tags: c++, qt, qml, refactoring, structure

My main lang is Python, but now i need to work with qml a bit, so i have the `first_file.qml` file with

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick3D 1.15
import QtQuick3D.Materials 1.15
import "../Elements"

Node {
    id: robotBaseNode
    property string pathToSource: "qrc:/static/mesh/"
    property string testPath: "qrc:/static/mesh/test/"
    property bool axisVisible: false
    property var currTcp

    function setJoints(pose) {
        if (window.robotModel === "R1") {
            link1Model.eulerRotation.y = pose[0]
            link2Node.eulerRotation.z = pose[1]
            link3Node.eulerRotation.z = pose[2]
            link4Model.eulerRotation.z = pose[3]
            link5Model.eulerRotation.y = -pose[4]
        } else if (window.robotModel === "R2") {
            link1Model.eulerRotation.y = pose[0]
            link2Node.eulerRotation.z = pose[1]
            link3Node.eulerRotation.z = pose[2]
            link4Model.eulerRotation.x = -(pose[3] - 90)
            link5Model.eulerRotation.x = -(pose[4] + 90)
            link6Model.eulerRotation.z = pose[5] - 90
        }
    }

    AxesHelper {
        scale: Qt.vector3d(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        lineWidth: window.robotModel === "R1" ? 0.5 : 0.35
        lineLength: window.robotModel === "R1" ? 100 : 500
        axesTCP: false
        showLine: robotBaseNode.axisVisible
        enableXYGrid: true
    }

    Node {
        id: tcp

        visible: window.robotRunning

        position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 0)
        rotation: Qt.quaternion(1, 0, 0, 0)

        Model {
            scale: Qt.vector3d(0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002)

            source: "#Sphere"

            materials: tcpMaterial
        }

        AxesHelper {
            scale: Qt.vector3d(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
            lineWidth: window.robotModel === "R1" ? 0.3 : 0.2
            lineLength: window.robotModel === "R1" ? 30 : 20
        }
    }

    Model {
        id: link0Model
        visible: true
        source: pathToSource + window.robotModel + "/link0.mesh"
        materials: defaultMaterial

        Node {
            id: link1Node
            position: Qt.vector3d(urdf[0].position[0], urdf[0].position[1],
                                  urdf[0].position[2])
            eulerRotation: Qt.vector3d(urdf[0].rotation[0],
                                       urdf[0].rotation[1], urdf[0].rotation[2])

            Model {
                id: link1Model
                source: pathToSource + window.robotModel + "/link1.mesh"
                materials: defaultMaterial
                eulerRotation.y: 0.0

                Node {
                    id: link2Node
                    eulerRotation.z: 0.0

                    Model {
                        id: link2Model
                        source: pathToSource + window.robotModel + "/link2.mesh"
                        materials: defaultMaterial
                        position: Qt.vector3d(urdf[1].position[0],
                                              urdf[1].position[1],
                                              urdf[1].position[2])
                        eulerRotation: Qt.vector3d(urdf[1].rotation[0],
                                                   urdf[1].rotation[1],
                                                   urdf[1].rotation[2])


                        }
                        ... (up to six models here)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move `setJoints` and `AxesHelper`s to another qml file, to store all config 'things' there. But i can't clearly understand the import methods in qml as well as i can't understand the areas of ​​visibility here. It's quite different from the python structure, imho. So, how can i do that (separation between model display and model config)?

Comment: If you are moving them to a qml file in the same directory or module, you don't need any import at all.

Comment: @JarMan thank you. I've tried it now, but i can't understand, how can i place the structure, like function setJoints, into the separatee file. I always have this error: `Expected a qualified name id`. I'm pretty sure that i can't just place the function outside the file. It needs some structured area, but i don't really understand what kind of this is needed.

Comment: You can have a `script.js` file that only holds the JavaScript code. Then, you should import that script. However, you need to send `link1Model` as an argument to your function since you do not have access to it from the `script.js` file. check https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-javascript-imports.html

Comment: You also consider moving your function to a QML singleton.